# Contact saving result is not showing in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a phone number saver in JavaScript. Everything is working, but when I search a name or a number in the search box no result is being shown:

```
function contact() {
    var nam1=prompt("Please enter the name");
    var num1=prompt("please enter the phone number");
}

contact();

function search() {
    var searc= prompt("Please enter the name of your contact or phone number");
}

search();

//search box

if ( searc == nam1 ) {
    alert("The phone Number is , " + num1);
}

if ( searc == num1 ) {
    alert("The Contact Name is , " + nam1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the variables scope.

Try this:

```
var nam1;
var num1;
var searc;

function contact() {

    nam1 = prompt("Please enter the name");
    num1 = prompt("please enter the phone number");

}

contact();

function search() {

    searc = prompt("Please enter the name of your contact or phone number");

}

search();

//search box

if ( searc == nam1 ) {

    alert("The phone Number is , " + num1);

}

if ( searc == num1 ) {

    alert("The Contact Name is , " + nam1);

}
```

Comment: @MISJHA you copied my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var nam1='';
var num1='';
var searc='';

function contact() {
    nam1=prompt("Please enter the name");
    num1=prompt("please enter the phone number");
}
contact();
function search() {
    searc= prompt("Please enter the name of your contact or phone number");
}
search();
//search box
if ( searc == nam1 ) {
    alert("The phone Number is , " + num1);
}
if ( searc == num1 ) {
    alert("The Contact Name is , " + nam1);
}
```

**Note:** You should `define these variables globally` so that they are available to you when you are
using.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript variables are only [declared in a specific scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope), either global or local to the function where they have been declared. Since you declared `nam1`, `num1` and `searc` in your *functions* they're not available outside.

Have a look at your error console. Usually you should get a `ReferenceError`, at least in strict mode. In order to prevent this declare your variables at the begin of your script, and *don't redeclare* them in your functions.